# Angular formly - Set watcher on templateOptions variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-formly

I want to set a watcher that will run a function for that field when a specific value changes in the templateOptions. The normal formly watcher can be used when you want to know that the input has been changed, so that does not work in my case. I have tried expressionProperties to but i cant get that to work eater.

I made a [js Bin](http://jsbin.com/xamigakeho/1/edit?html,js,output) as an example.
There are two input fields when you mouse over one field templateOptions.mouseOver becomes true and on mouse leave the mouseOver boolean becomes false. What can i do so that when mouseOver changes a function is run?

Answer (score 0):

You simply can put a controller on the field if you want to do it for each individual field, or you can put it in the template itself if the function will be the same for each field, after specifying a function to run in ng-mouseOver.  Like This:

```
formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper([

      {
        template: [
                    'editorEnabled: {{to.editorEnabled}}',
                    '<div ng-mouseover="to.editorEnabled=true; Update()" ng-mouseleave="to.editorEnabled=false; Update()">',
                        '<formly-transclude></formly-transclude>',
                    '</div>'
                ].join(' '),
        controller: function($scope) {
           $scope.Update = function() {
              //Code to run when value changes
           }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

Of if you are doing it in each individual field(if the functions you are going to be calling are going to be different for each field) you would do:

```
vm.fields = [
      {
        key: 'textField1',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Input1',
          type: 'text',
          value:vm.model.textField1,
          editorEnabled: false
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.Run = function() {
             alert('Changed!');
          }
        }
      },
```